# Codeigniter 4. How to load View file with #ID added to Url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the form validation class in codeigniter 4. All working fine but when it reloads the form with the errors the page is at the top again. In Codeigniter 3 it was enough to add #id in code:

```
$this->load->view('form#anchor');
```

In CI4:

```
return view('form#anchor', ['errors' => $this->validation->getErrors()]);
```

But in CI4 not working:

```
CodeIgniter\View\Exceptions\ViewException

Invalid file: welcome_message#section-price.php
```

Comment: Please add the error to your question

Comment: CodeIgniter\View\Exceptions\ViewException

Invalid file: welcome_message#section-price.php